# How to tell if the ISO used to install Ubuntu is compromised?

Tags: system-installation, live-usb, security, iso, hacking

I just want to know if there's any way to know if the ISO I installed was compromised. Is there any way I could tell by looking for it in Ubuntu right now? If so, how and what should I do?

Also, may I ask if the usb I used to install the ISO in, will the usb and ISO be reinfected or not when I use "compromised" OS to make a live USB with it? Or will it not be affected?

I didn't check the hash of the ISO and I'm thinking the ISO and OS is compromised seeing that I left it alone and it was unlocked.

That ISO that I used to install Ubuntu was erased on my usb so I have no way of checking its hash. Only I can check the newly downloaded one.

Comment: You can check the md5sum: Run the command `md5sum filename.iso` and compare to the value that you can find via [this link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuHashes). The Ubuntu iso files contain the read-only file system iso9660, and it is very unlikely that it will be infected, when it is in your computer.

Comment: Forgot to mention that the ISO I used was erased, included it in the original question.

Comment: Well, obviously, you cannot check what you erased, but you can check the newly downloaded iso file. If you download from the official Ubuntu web site, I think the weak link in the chain is the file transfer via the internet. There may be file transfer errors, and they will be found, if you check with md5sum.

Comment: So the download and its data is one of the sign the system is compromised? Is there more?

Comment: Why do you think your system is compromised? What signs do you see? If the system is new, you can always make a fresh installation, which will overwrite the previous system. But if it is old and you have invested a lot of time and effort in it, you would like to keep it. -- *I could answer about the iso file, but I am no security expert*, so I cannot really  help you search for signs of a compromised system.

Comment: I see. I suspect it is because, someone who lives with me infected my gadgets and I fear they could infect my laptop as well. I'm also curious if I make a live-usb using the same laptop will make the infection stay or disappear because I reinstalled a new one.

Comment: If you 1. download an Ubuntu iso file from the official Ubuntu web site, 2. check it with md5sum, 3. clone from it to a USB pendrive (for example with the Ubuntu Startup Disk Creator), then you will have a read-only and live-only USB drive with the iso 9660 file system. It will not get infected.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1122910/will-the-iso-installed-on-the-live-usb-be-infected-if-made-with-a-compromised-ub ????

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Will the ISO installed on the live-usb be infected if made with a compromised Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1122910/will-the-iso-installed-on-the-live-usb-be-infected-if-made-with-a-compromised-ub)